# How can I view my virtualbox guest unix filesystem from the host windows file/text editor?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, windows, virtualbox, editors

I'm running Ubuntu/CentOS in a virtualbox guest and am trying to configure various services to run on it (nginx, php, memcache and more). I'm finding it slow to use the console editors and hard to remember file locations, as well as the chore of typing out their full file-folder names all the time.

I'd like to be able to navigate and edit system files and folders from my windows environment using the editors I use day to day: notepad++, webstorm etc.  Mainly so I can familiarise myself with the contents of various folders in a visual way (albeit a small difference).

Essentially, I guess I'm asking if there is a way to directly access the guest filesystem as root or a sudoer.  So, is there some way I can set up my guest ubuntu server and then navigate it's filesystem from windows?  Or do I have to install a GUI in my guest and use that instead? (this is frowned upon, so I hear).  I expect to serve most of my website content from a shared folder for development purposes, so config files and things could be in a shared directory, but obviously there are many other system folders I'd need to have access to as well, such as `/etc`, `/var`, `/opt`, `/usr`, ...

Comment: This is not easily possible, as far as I know. But it seems you want to do this out of a desire to avoid using Linux tools. But there many editors on Linux. Some of them are quite like the Windows ones you are used to. Have you explored the options?

Comment: You could use NFS or samba to export (all or part of) the guest fs, and mount it on the windows host as a network file share.   but I'd follow @FaheemMitha's advice if i were you.  If you're running a GUI desktop environment on your ubuntu guest, you can use the graphical file browser it provides.  Otherwise, you could use a text mode file browser like Midnight Commander aka `mc`.

Comment: That's a really bad idea, editing Linux OS/config files on Windows.

Comment: Is the VM running while you're doing it? (Otherwise, this question turns into "how do I access the contents of a vmdk or similar")

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I use nano/vim alot but it's just not very easy to remember all the keys that make them fast and efficient (brain us full with the Windows/Mac shortcuts). I've used Gedit a lot and that's fine for text editing, but obviously it needs a GUI installed, which was the thing that I was trying to avoid (I've seen a lot of arguments against installing GUIs on servers).  I can see Samba is an option, but clearly that has it's own set of problems when it comes to real-time editing.

Comment: @Tim S.  I know.  But setting up a dev environment on Unix is really slow and painful compared to mac and windows.  Having to do everything on an 80-char screen with text-only editors means it's taking me days, rather than hours by comparison.  I know Unix-pros will have a zillion shortcuts and optimisations, but the point here is how does someone like me find the best of both worlds without crippling the benefits of Unix-based systems?

Comment: `nano` is too hard to remember how to use?  nano???     Do you know how you get to be a 'Unix pro with a zillion shortcuts'?  You start off as a newbie and practice.  With `vi`, for example, you only need to remember about half a dozen commands for basic usage.....and over time you gradually learn more and more of the advanced features.   BTW if you edit unix text files on Windows you will have problems with line-endings.  Windows expects CR+LF.  Unix expects LF only.  Unless you use an editor which can convert between them (e.g. `vim`), you'll have to manually convert them each way.

Comment: BTW, use `putty` on windows to ssh into your VM and you won't be limited to 80 character wide terminals.  Make your `putty` terminal as wide as will fit on your screen, in whatever (mono-spaced) font and font-size you prefer.

Comment: @Cas  Haha, yes, nano doesn't 'just work' like Webstorm, notepadd++, VS etc.  It's hard enough dealing with those as well as the new Mac ones (new to me, I mean), but my overriding point here is whether you can *avoid* being a unix pro, since that would necessitate time investment I simply don't have.  I'm not against the idea of it (Unix interests me a great deal), but I use it infrequently enough to make re-visiting it a chore, since I've forgotten the useful tips I learned since last time.  Especially concerning locations/relevance of various files and shortcut keys.

Comment: @Cas Thanks for the tip on SSH, that seems like the sensible approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your host is Windows, you can use Samba to share files from the client with the host. However, you should not edit any configuration files using the host's tools, as they might look the same after editing, but will most likely get newlines inserted.

If you have trouble editing files with `vi`, use something mode-less like `nano` or `emacs` for editing.

On the other hand there is nothing that speaks against running a graphical interface on a VM client (assuming the memory overhead is acceptable on the machine). But beware that editing configuration files most often still needs to be done as root. Once you have a graphical interface you can browse your filesystem with the same ease as you do on the host.

Comment: Thanks, Anthon.  As per my comments above, I have used nano and vim, but I find them much harder to use than windows/mac gui editors (none of my shortcuts work!).  I use gedit on non-server Ubuntu guests, but I've been told not to install GUIs on servers, so I assume that's not an option.

Comment: As I indicated, there is overhead in running GUI. You can however install X and a desktop and only start it when you need it. I don't see any problem with that on a server. In fact that is better than mangling some configuration file because of user-unfriendliness/inexperience. But that is just what my 32 years of running Unix/Linux servers tells me.

Comment: That sounds like an ideal solution!  I'll give that a try.  If you happen to have a link to some good guidance on it, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks, dude.

Comment: Setup a new VM with a graphical user interface to experiment with. Deactivate the display-mananger service (`sudo systemctl disable display-manager`) reboot the VM and see if that indeed stops the graphs from starting. Check that `X` is not in the process list. Then start with `sudo systemctl start display-manager`. Sorry I have no links with a step by step guide, but that is how I would proceed. Once that works, install the relevant packages on your CentOS server VM and repeat the deactivation there.

Comment: That's really useful, thankyou so much, Anthon.  I really appreciate it! :)